# How can I use Google Spreadsheet to format Date in DD/MM/YYYY format?

Tags: google-sheets, date

First thing's first: my spreadsheet's locale is properly  set to UK:

[image]

If I paste in the following date:

```
30/09/2013 21:15
```

Then click Format > Number > Date time

[image]

Nothing changes. I also can't seem to sort by date.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but the `30/09/2013 21:15` you're pasting in *IS* in dd/mm/yyyy. It matches the *date time* format in the drop down.

Comment: If I paste in your date *after* changing the spreadsheet settings it works fine for me. Alternatively try setting the number format of the cell *first* and then pasting in the data.

Comment: @phantom42 Google spreadsheets adds seconds if it parses the date properly (note I originally said 'milliseconds', this isn't correct). I've re-tested on the latest Google Drive and pasting then changing the format works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has now been resolved by Google Spreadsheets. Pasting in the date:

```
30/09/2013 21:15
```

And clicking Format > Number > Date time now immediately turns the cell into a date time cell (you can see this as it adds seconds).

[image]